# Android webview not rendering bootstrap span label

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, webview, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to render a simple HTML using Bootstrap, but label component is not displaying correctly. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="label label-success">
            Test
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

The content is loaded from remote server using the default Android WebView.

Answer (score 0):

style="display:inline;"

It is displayed when you specify inline "display:inline;"
Reason unknown

Comment: please be more specific in your answer where possible and add the reason as well as any side effects.